# Which is better using Android-xamarin with WCF service or web service?

Tags: web-services, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android, mobile-application

Recently, I've started learning to develop mobile apps using Xamarin.Android.
I should implement a service that communicate with database to get and set data,
My mobile application is the only client for this service.
Which is better to implement this service using web service or WCF service ?? 
please note that I don not have any knowledge about web service or WCF service, so i will learn on of them from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a REST service, not WCF for a Xamarin app. You could create a service using ASP.NET MVC or Web API and use that for your service endpoint. Then you could use HTTPCLIENT in your Xamarin app to call the service. This is my preferred method when I have to create the app and the service.

You can add http client to your PCL in your mobile app via a nuget package - Microsoft.Net. HttpClient.

If you have more specific questions, you can post them as separate questions. For more information about how to do either of those things, you should check out Xamarins documentation and developer forums.

Comment: I did search on google about REST service, but I found something called RESTFull service. are they the same ??. @valdetero

Comment: Yes, they refer to the same thing.